# Why to switch user when I am already in the group with the same name?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

On our ubuntu linux server: I got a permission error when access: /home/abc/data/. I was told I need to be added to the abc group. They added me. I am still having the same permission error when cd to that directory. Then they told me I have to `sudo su - abc` to switch to abc user to access that directory.
Why do I have to su to abc since I am in the abc group already? Is abc a user, not a group? I am confused.

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You could probably ask on [ubuntu.se] instead.

Comment: Did you log out and log in again?  Groups are only checked when your session is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abc` might be a user, or a group, or both -- which depends on how your system is set up, but generally on Ubuntu, every user has a corresponding group with the same name.  So it is probably both a user and a group.

Accessing the directory in question might be a question of either user or group permissions.  Try doing `ls -ld /home/abc`, which will show you the permissions on that directory.  It will give you an output something like

```
drwxr-xr-x 248 abc   abc   16384 Feb 24 09:17 /home/abc
```

The letters at the beginning are the permissions.  In this case the first `rwx` are the 'user' permissions (meaning the user `abc` has read, write, and execute permission here) while the second `r-x` are the 'group' permissions, (meaning group `abc` has read and execute permissions, but not write permissions).

If the group permissions are adequate for what you want to do, you need only be in group `abc`.  If on the other hand, you need something only allowed by the user permissions, you need to be user `abc`.  The latter is generally considered bad form and a mis-configuration.

To see what groups you are a member of, use the `groups` command.